# Sys_Prop_Setting_version parameter in Android.Provider.Settings.System Class

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-settings

I want a parameter from **Sys_Prop_Setting_version** in android which gives information about the secure system setting, containing system preferences that applications can read but are not allowed to write. I searched this parameter in **Android.Provider.Settings.System** class, I didn't find it, but what I found is that this **parameter is present in [xamarin -API](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Provider.Settings+System/) but not present in [android-api](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html)** I want this parameter how should I get it? what's the difference in these API's? for my application, I am using android-API marshmallow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I searched this parameter in Android.Provider.Settings.System class, I didn't find it, but what I found is that this parameter is present in xamarin -API but not present in android-api I want this parameter how should I get it?

This string `Sys_Prop_Setting_version` is removed from API level 23 to 24, you can checked the following documentations:

[Android API Differences Report](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/24/changes.html).

[Class android.provider.Settings.Global](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/24/changes/android.provider.Settings.Global.html#android.provider.Settings.Global.SYS_PROP_SETTING_VERSION).

[Class android.provider.Settings.Secure](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/24/changes/android.provider.Settings.Secure.html#android.provider.Settings.Secure.SYS_PROP_SETTING_VERSION).

[Class android.provider.Settings.System](https://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/24/changes/android.provider.Settings.System.html#android.provider.Settings.System.SYS_PROP_SETTING_VERSION).

> what's the difference in these API's? for my application, I am using android-API marshmallow.

This `Sys_Prop_Setting_version` was presented in three different tables and the [SysPropSettingVersion Field](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Provider.Settings+Global.SysPropSettingVersion/) in Xamarin is the same one as the one in `android.provider.Settings.Global` table. Usually apis in Xamarin.Android are like the encapsulations of native android apis, they are the same, so this string field can also be found in `Android.Provider.Settings.Secure` and `Android.Provider.Settings.System` classes.

Since you're using android api marshmallow, it should be available. But I tested the code on android 6.0 device:

```
var sysprop = Android.Provider.Settings.Global.SysPropSettingVersion;
var settings = Android.Provider.Settings.Global.GetString(ApplicationContext.ContentResolver, sysprop);
```

It returns a null by my side, and I also tested:

`Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(ApplicationContext.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.SysPropSettingVersion);` and `Android.Provider.Settings.System.GetString(ApplicationContext.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.System.SysPropSettingVersion);`, all returns a null by my side. But if you want to find some other read only values in system secure settings, it works fine, for example:

```
Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.GetString(ApplicationContext.ContentResolver, Android.Provider.Settings.Secure.AndroidId);
```

Then I tried to figure out what is this value used for, by checking this [document](http://www.android-doc.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.Global.html), I found nothing.

It seems that this `Sys_Prop_Setting_version` was used for getting the android api level of the device(not for sure, I saw some code used this to get OS version), if you want to do this, you can simply code like this:

```
var version = Android.OS.Build.VERSION.Release;
```